# Xcode - run script only when source file is added or removed

Tags: python, xcode, xcode9

In my project, I have a Python script that scans the source directory and updates a source file with what it finds. I’d like this script to only run when it needs to. At the moment, I have this script in a Run Script build phase with Input Files set to `$(PROJECT).xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` and Output Files set to the updated source file. This means that the scripts runs when I add new files but it also runs whenever I change project settings. When the script runs unnecessarily, part of the project is recompiled even though none of the source files have changed. This is kind of annoying when all I want to do is tweak some settings.

Is there some way that I can avoid the unnecessary recompilation and just run the script when new source files are added or removed from the project?

---

I guess I could manually run the script whenever I add or remove a source file.

---

I think that Xcode is recompiling because the modification date on the file is changed. Python updates the modification date when you flush to a file. So I guess I could just write to the file only when the output is different to the output file. I’m pretty sure reading a file won’t change the modification date. That seems like a lot of fluffing around though. If anyone’s got a better solution, please let me know!